# Pattern recognition on 3d geometry

Tags: computational-geometry

How can I identify that an object is patterned (or symmetrical at least?). For example, I give to the algorithm a wall of red bricks. I want it to recognize that if it takes 1,2 or 4 bricks, it's possible to recreate the whole wall with translation. I didn't find anything in literature, I probably have not tried the right keywords. Any suggestion is welcome.